# Checking proof that space is not path connected

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, connectedness

I was going through Munkres and ran into a problem asking to show that
\begin{align*}
X & = \operatorname{cl} \left( \left\{ \left( x, \sin \frac{1}{x} \right) : 0 < x \leq 1 \right\} \right) \\ 
& = \left\{ \left( x, \sin \frac{1}{x} \right) : 0 < x \leq 1 \right\} \cup \left( \{0\} \times [-1, 1] \right)
\end{align*}
is not path connected. Having taken analysis, my first instinct was to say, "Oh! Weird stuff happens with $\sin \frac{1}{x}$ when you approach $0$!" So I came up with this. Does it work?

So let $p \in \{0\} \times [-1, 1] $, and $q = (1, \sin 1)$. I claim there does not exist a continuous function $f: [0, 1] \to X$ such that $f(0) = p, f(1) = q$. To do so, assume for contradiction that $f: [0, 1] \to X$ is continuous, and $f(0) = p, f(1) = q$. Then since $\{ 0 \} \times [-1, 1]$ is closed, we know that $f^{-1} (\{ 0 \} \times [-1, 1])$ is compact, so we set
\begin{align*}
c & = \max \left( f^{-1} (\{ 0 \} \times [-1, 1]) \right) \\
& = \max \{ t \in [0, 1] : f(t) = 0 \},
\end{align*}
where the maximum must exist by the extreme value theorem, and $c < 1$ because $f(1) = (1, \sin 1)$.

Now, we aim to show that $f$ is not continuous at $c$. Assume without loss of generality that $\pi_{2} (f(c)) \leq 0$. Let $0 < \epsilon < 1$, and let $\delta > 0$ be arbitrary. Then since $f$ is continuous, and thus so is $\pi_{1} \circ f$, we know by the intermediate value theorem that $\pi_{1}(f([c, c + \delta)))$ must contain an interval $[0, r)$ for some $r > 0$. Choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ sufficiently large that $0 < \frac{1}{2 \pi N + \pi / 2} < r$. Then there exists $t \in [c, c + \delta)$ s.t. $f(t) = \left( \frac{1}{2 \pi N + \pi / 2}, 1 \right) $. Then
\begin{align*}
\| f(t) - f(c) \| & = \sqrt{ ( \pi_{2}(f(t)) - \pi_{2}(f(c)) )^{2} + ( \pi_{1}(f(t)) - \pi_{1}(f(c)) )^{2} } \\
& \geq \pi_{2}(f(t)) - \pi_{2}(f(c)) \\
& = 1 - \pi_{2}(f(c)) \\
& \geq 1 \\
& > \epsilon ,
\end{align*}
so $f$ is not right-continuous at $c$. This completes the proof.

Is the proof above correct? Is there another more typical one? Thanks.

Comment: Other proof: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1201319/4280

Comment: I get a 404 for that link